# Is java.lang.Process thread-safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm starting a process in the background using `ProcessBuilder.start`.

While the process runs, I repeatedly call `Process.info()` to show some data like actual processing time in the UI.
At the same time, there is a background thread which may call `Process.destroy` to destroy the process.

So two threads are concurrently calling methods on the `Process`. Do I need to manually synchronize these calls? Can something bad happen when `Process.destroy` is called while another thread is in the middle of running `Process.info`? Or is `Process` guaranteed to be thread-safe?

The JavaDoc of `Process` doesn't mention thread safety. The implementation of `info` looks like it could be thread-safe, but `destroy` is implemented natively, so I don't know for sure.

Comment: It's not specified, so you should synchronize (or otherwise ensure exclusive access) if you have concerns. A read-write lock may be a suitable choice, since there is no obvious reason to exclude multiple processes calling `info()` simultaneously.

Comment: Nice idea regarding read-write lock! Although in my case, I have only one reader and one writer, so it won't make any difference. Still, I like the idea.